# Converting string into byte dynamically C#

Tags: c#

So to start with, it's not a duplicated post as my question is a little bit more special than that.

I know how to convert a string into byte remotely using the File.ReadAllBytes(); command and it works perfectly for remote purpose.

Now I want to achieve the same thing without using the File.ReadAllBytes(); method and do everything inside the code

This is a clear exemple of what i want to achieve exactly :

```
string myString = @"0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03";
```

So this is a normal string with 19 character

```
byte[] myByte = new byte[4] {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03};
```

And this is what I want to finish with

Is it possible to convert the string variable into the byte variable dynamically without using the I/O command ?

Comment: @RyanWilson, unfortunately it doesn't because it will convert every char into bytes even the "," ones

Comment: Then split and parse... Where is the problem?

Comment: @Selvin I wish it was as easy as that, it has to be done the way i described for my project to work, i can't just copy/paste it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one liner for you, splits the string on the comma, uses `Linq` to select each value from the string array and convert it to a byte and finally calls `.ToArray` to give you the `byte` array:

```
string myString = @"0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03";

byte[] myByte = myString.Split(',')
                 .Select(a => Convert.ToByte(a, 16))
                 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```cs
public byte[] ParseBytes(string bytes)
{
    var splitBytes = bytes.Split(',');
    byte[] result = new byte[splitBytes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = Convert.ToByte(splitBytes[i], 16);
    }
    return result;
}

byte[] myByte = ParseBytes(myString);
```

Just keep in mind you should add exception handling.

Comment: or as a lonq one-liner:`var outBytes =  bytes.Split(',').Select(b=>Convert.ToByte(b,16)).ToArray();`